# How to choose only the first 5 we recorded?

Tags: mysql, activerecord, yii

Yii framework! :)

MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `post` (
  `post_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `post_content` text,
  `category_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`post_ID`),
  KEY `FK_post_cat` (`category_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

I need for some Yii framework tutorial dashboard (config edit, view last event and so on)..
I have a MySQL table posts need to choose from the last 5 posts, how to do it? Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best would be with a scope in your Post model. From the [guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar#named-scopes):

```
class Post extends CActiveRecord
{
    ......
    public function scopes()
    {
        return array(
            'published'=>array(
                'condition'=>'status=1',
            ),
            'recently'=>array(
                'order'=>'create_time DESC',
                'limit'=>5,
            ),
        );
    }
}
```